# itext sharp is creating a corrupt pdf after adding an image

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The PDF is coming to me from a http get.
I have looked at several examples here on SO and haven't been able to squash this bug.

Note: I am only saving the PDF's for debugging purposes, after I get this figured out it will be totally in memory and post the modified PDF to an api as base64.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//get Invoice PDF
Byte[] pdf_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(GetInvoicePDF(account, invoice, config));

//Save a Debug Copy
using( FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\temp\\b4-invoice-" + invoice.id + ".pdf") )
{
    fs.Write(pdf_bytes, 0, (int)pdf_bytes.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}

Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
MemoryStream msPDF = new MemoryStream(pdf_bytes);

//Create Bitmap 
System.Drawing.Bitmap Bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(333, 195);
using( System.Drawing.Graphics gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Bmp) )
using( System.Drawing.SolidBrush brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)) )
{
    gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 333, 195);
}


Image img = Image.GetInstance(Bmp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);


PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msPDF);

doc.Open();//Open Document to write
doc.Add(img);
doc.Close();
doc.Dispose();

Byte[] pdf_bytes_out = msPDF.ToArray();

//Save a Debug Copy
using( FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\temp\\invoice-" + invoice.id + ".pdf") )
{
    fs.Write(pdf_bytes_out, 0, (int)pdf_bytes_out.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're writing two PDFs to a file. Which one of both os corrupt? I don't see anything related to iText in the file you retrieve from the web.

Comment: The modified one. Don't you see the "PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msPDF);"
Actually I'm writing 2 PDF's from a single source, one before modification and one after. Only the PDF that runs through iTextSharp is the corrupt one. The first one writes out fine.

Comment: What @Bruno tried to tell you is that you put two distinct pdfs into `MemoryStream msPDF`, one after the other. And a file containing two pdfs, one after the other, no envelope, will never be a valid pdf, no matter how the individual pdfs are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out I didn't need to use the doc object at all.

```
//get Invoice PDF
Byte[] pdf_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(GetInvoicePDF(account, invoice, config));

//Save a Debug Copy
using( FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\temp\\b4-invoice-" + invoice.id + ".pdf") )
{
    fs.Write(pdf_bytes, 0, (int)pdf_bytes.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}

MemoryStream msPDF = new MemoryStream();

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf_bytes);
Rectangle rect = reader.GetPageSize(1);


using( PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, msPDF) )
{
    // modify the pdf content
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
    //cb.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.GREEN);
    //cb.SetLineWidth(1f);
    cb.SetColorFill(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE);
    cb.Rectangle(rect.GetLeft(0), rect.GetTop(0) - 250, 350, 250);
    cb.Fill();
    //cb.Stroke();
}
reader.Close();


Byte[] pdf_bytes_out = msPDF.GetBuffer();

using( FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\temp\\invoice-" + invoice.id + ".pdf") )
{
    fs.Write(pdf_bytes_out, 0, (int)pdf_bytes_out.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```